# jQuery fadeIn()

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

What does it mean if fadeIn() goes from an opacity of 0% to 100% as soon as the fade timeperiod is up?

I've got this:

```
function ThreadPost(post, appendToElementId) {

    if (post != null) {
        $("#" + appendToElementId).append("<ol id='" + post.Id + "'></ol>");
        $("#" + post.Id).hide().html(PostHtml(post)).fadeIn(5000);
    }
}
```

PostHtml() returns a "`<li>....</li>`".

When the page loads, the `<ol>` is hidden. Then, after 5 seconds, the `<ol>` suddenly appears. No fading occurs. Using Chrome.

Comment: From where you fire the above function? Is it within document.ready?

Comment: All I can say is that it is working for me in FF, IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I've had all kinds of weird issues with jQuery fadeIn() and show() just popping in instead of animating. See if this works better:

```
$("#" + post.Id).css({opacity: 0.0}).html(PostHtml(post)).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try taking out the `hide()` and let me know what it does?  Or perhaps move the `hide()` to after you set the html?  The fadeIn method should hide it automatically anyway, but it's worth a shot.

Also, can you provide any more information about what the `PostHtml` method does?  It could be that it's defining styles that are making things behave strangely.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Damovisa in that we could do with knowing what the **PostHtml** method does - if it does an Ajax call then it might be completing after the **fadeIn** timeout has expired, hence the fading in effect not appearing to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try hardcoding PostHtml(post) as `<li>test</li>`.  See below:

```
function ThreadPost(post, appendToElementId) {

    if (post != null) {
        $("#" + appendToElementId).append("<ol id='" + post.Id + "'></ol>");
        $("#" + post.Id).hide().html("<li>test</li>").fadeIn(5000);
    }
}
```

If that works with the hardcoded `<li>`, then you know it's PostHtml(post), causing your issue.  When I hard code, the fade works as expected in IE, FF, and Chrome.

Comment: I pasted this exact code in and the <li>test</li> is hidden until 5 seconds when it suddenly appears.

Comment: That is what you were expecting, correct?  So, if you now replace the hardcoded <pre><li></pre> with <pre>PostHtml(post)</pre>, does it then no longer fade in as expected for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling show() right before fadeIn():

```
function ThreadPost(post, appendToElementId) {

    if (post != null) {
        $("#" + appendToElementId).append("<ol id='" + post.Id + "'></ol>");
        $("#" + post.Id).hide().html(PostHtml(post)).show().fadeIn(5000);
    }
}
```

or simply get rid of the hide():

```
function ThreadPost(post, appendToElementId) {

    if (post != null) {
        $("#" + appendToElementId).append("<ol id='" + post.Id + "'></ol>");
        $("#" + post.Id).html(PostHtml(post)).fadeIn(5000);
    }
}
```